# Bypass Youtube's restriction on embedding copyrighted videos on 3rd party websites

Tags: php, javascript, youtube, youtube-api

When embedding Youtube videos onto my site I sometimes come across this error: "This video contains content from UMG. It is restricted to playback on certain sites."

I would like to bypass this restriction. How have sites like http://listentoyoutube.com bypassed these restrictions? Also, how would I go about getting my site onto Youtubes list of "playback on certain sites."?

Comment: Geez, you didn't even provide an example video.

Comment: "bypass"... so your question is about pirating?

Comment: Please read the last question @Christophe, possibly pricing and not pirating.

Comment: @GlennDayton I am afraid this is not a programming question then

Comment: I believe youtube detects where the viewer is located and displays that error if they aren't allowed to view that video in there area.

Comment: @Christophe Certainly listentoyoutube.com had to program some way to bypass the restrictions.

Comment: @GlennDayton Not in any sort of legitimate, within-the-TOS sort of way.

Comment: Why don't you guys forget about the TOS and the legal BS, and worry about the programming aspect and possibly help me out a little bit.

Comment: Many of us run sites with TOSes we'd like to stick, and as such, we're mostly not going to help you circumvent legitimate (if at times annoying) restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those certain sites are going to be sites UMG likes - most likely, their own marketing and news sites. You're not going to get onto those lists.

If sites like listentoyoutube.com are getting around the restriction, it's likely by pretending to be a normal YouTube.com visitor. This is almost certainly a violation of the YouTube TOS, and I'd imagine they get blocked regularly.